# NSFetchedResultsController / CoreData with multiple threads issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm currently developping an application which uses CoreData and a NSFectchedResultsController. This application only contains one UITableView which uses a NSFetchedResultsController.

**1/** When the application is launched, another thread is detached. In this new thread, a WS call permits to retrieve data from a web server. After the WS call, I store data in my CoreData DB with another NSManagedObjectContext (Apple's best practice: Another thread => Another context). I have to delete all objects of this entity before saving new objects. I merge this other context with the main context via mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification.

```
        // Data Manager (in another thread)
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   addObserver:self
                                                selector:@selector(contextDidSave:)
                                                name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                object:context];
        [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self getPersistentStoreCoordinator]];

        ...

        for (NSManagedObject * obj in objects) 
        {
            [context deleteObject:obj];
        }

        ...

        for(NSDictionary *serverObj in serverObjects)
        {
            objAd =  [NSEntityDescription
                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" 
                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
            ...
        }

        [context save:&error];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:context];
        [context release];

        ...

        - (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
        {

            SEL selector = @selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:); 
            [[self getContext] performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
        }

        - (NSManagedObjectContext *) getContext
        {
            return [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        }

        - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) getPersistentStoreCoordinator
        {
            return [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentStoreCoordinator];
        }
```

**2/** Here is my NSFectchedResultsController's getter:

```
        // UIView
    - (NSFetchedResultsController*) offersFRC {

        if (offersFRC == nil) 
        {
            NSManagedObjectContext *l_ManagedObjectContext = [[DataManager sharedDataManager] getContext];

            NSFetchRequest *l_FetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

            NSEntityDescription *l_Entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:l_ManagedObjectContext];
            [l_FetchRequest setEntity:l_Entity];

            [l_FetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:5];

            NSNumber *sortType = [self.searchCriterions objectForKey:@"sortType"];
            NSSortDescriptor *l_SortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[Constants getFieldNameBySortType:sortType] ascending:[Constants isAscendingBySortType:sortType]];
            [l_FetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:l_SortDescriptor, nil]];
            [l_SortDescriptor release];

            NSFetchedResultsController *l_FetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:l_FetchRequest                                                                                                      managedObjectContext:l_ManagedObjectContext 
                sectionNameKeyPath:nil                                                                                                     
                cacheName:nil];
            [l_FetchRequest release];

            [self setOffersFRC:l_FetchedResultsController];
            [l_FetchedResultsController release],l_FetchedResultsController = nil;

            [self.offersFRC setDelegate:self];
        }

        return offersFRC;
    }
```

**3/** I've got the following error when the application is launched:

```
        2012-02-29 11:56:09.119 Nanopost[1996:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception      'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x5c3c760 <x-coredata://E176B0A1-275B-4332-9231-49FD88238C2B/Ads/p231>''
    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02bfe919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e595de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreData                            0x028b833f _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 1407
    3   CoreData                            0x028b5ee3 _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 499
    4   CoreData                            0x028b9f3f _sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 95
    5   CoreData                            0x0292a010 _PF_Handler_Public_GetProperty + 160
    6   Foundation                          0x02442c4f -[NSSortDescriptor compareObject:toObject:] + 128
    7   CoreData                            0x0297db5e +[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _insertIndexForObject:inArray:lowIdx:highIdx:sortDescriptors:] + 286
    8   CoreData                            0x0297e1b2 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _postprocessInsertedObjects:] + 402
    9   CoreData                            0x029841bc -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 1804
    10  Foundation                          0x02380c1d _nsnote_callback + 145
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x02bd6cf9 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 745
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x02b5611a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
    13  Foundation                          0x023767c2 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 134
    14  CoreData                            0x028c0519 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 89
    15  CoreData                            0x028f802b -[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:] + 1579
    16  Foundation                          0x02395e9a __NSThreadPerformPerform + 251
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x02bdfd7f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x02b3e2cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x02b3d7c6 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x02b3d280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x02b3d1a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x031e62c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x031e638d GSEventRun + 115
    24  UIKit                               0x0063cb58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    25  Nanopost                            0x0000230a main + 170
    26  Nanopost                            0x00002255 start + 53
    )
    terminate called after throwing an instance of '_NSCoreDataException'
```

**Important Notes**:

- It crashes only on iOS4
- controllerWillChangeContent is the last function called in my code before application's crash. controllerDidChangeContent / didChangeObject/ didChangeSection are not called.
- When I comment [l_FetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:5] => No more crashes
- When I add a [context save:&error] after objects deletion and before new objects insertion => No more crashes
- When I use [l_FetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:24] => Crashes
- When I use [l_FetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:25] => No more crashes

I have spent a lot of time trying to understand this issue so Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Thomas

**Edit 1 (@Jody):**
Hi Jody and thank you very much for your answers!

Here is the code used for handling contextDidSave:

```
    - (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        SEL selector = @selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:); 
        [[self getContext] performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
```

"you first have to tell me more about the context you are using":

I use 2 contexts in this application:

- N° 1 : Created by default in the AppDelegate when you create XCodeProject. This context is used by my FRC and permits to display UITableView's rows.
- N° 2 : Created in my "DataManager" (first code block in my post), a singleton which permits to refresh my DB (WS Call, deletion, re-insertion, save).

When context N° 2 is saved, contextDidSave is called to merge this context with the main context (context N° 1). After that, my FRC delegate's method "controllerWillChangeContent" is called. I don't think it will help to show the code contained in this method because even if I just put a NSLog, it crashes after this method (I put a lot of NSLog and the NSLog contained in controllerWillChangeContent is the last which is displayed before the crash).

I have posted on Apple Dev Forum and there is an interesting answer: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/152172?tstart=0

**Edit 2 (@Jody):**
Hi Jody!

As you can see in the following method, my FRC doesn't use the MOC from the other thread:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) getContext
    {
        return [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }
```

This method of my "DataManager" returns AppDelegate's MOC (= main thread MOC)

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting from the database in one context, so you must appropriately refresh your other contexts, and, specifically, get rid of your object references to the deleted data.

What is your code for handling contextDidSave:?  Also, what does your FRC delegate do with the data update notifications?

**EDIT**

It looks like you are mixing up your managed object contexts.  You are using one in your data manager to load and modify the database...

```
// Data Manager (in another thread)
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
```

And then using the "default" MOC to pull that data into your app via the notification, yet it looks like your fetched results controller is also trying to use the MOC from the other thread...

```
NSManagedObjectContext *l_ManagedObjectContext = [[DataManager sharedDataManager] getContext];
```

It should probably be using the main MOC (from your app delegate) as well.

Comment: You should not put code in a comment because it has no formatting.  Also, editing the question to provide a better question is the way to go.  As for the code, before I even address the DidSave handling, you first have to tell me more about the context you are using... again, where did it come from?  How was it created?  What is its relationship to the MR contexts?

Comment: Oops.  Same questions but disregard the MR part (was answering on the road (at a Hardees) and got it mixed with another question.  Sorry for any confusion.